# Hibernate is *NOT* throwing an exception (I think it should)

Tags: java, hibernate

The Hibernate JavaDoc states that `Session.update(Object o)` would raise an exception if there's already a persistent instance of `o`, right?

```
If there is a persistent instance with the same identifier, an exception is thrown.
```

However, the following code doesn't throw anything when I run it. And I think it should!

```
Email email = new Email("andre", "girafa", "hi");

Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

session.save(email);
session.update(email);
session.update(email);

tx.commit();

// didn't throw... Let's try again

tx = session.beginTransaction();

session.update(email);
session.update(email);

tx.commit();
session.close();

// still nothing! :(
```

As you can say, **twice** I try to do multiple `update()`s, but still Hibernate's taking easy on me.

Anybody has a hunch why?

**EDIT:** it seems that it would only throw if *another equivalent object*, for instance, `email2` with the same ID as `email`. I guess the documentation was kinda sloppy there.

Comment: Yes! the docs never want to write it clear and it lead me to this question!

Answer (score 8):

Update in Hibernate is not UPDATE in SQL language. Hibernate handles SQL UPDATEs 
*automatically* through state cache in Session object.

But it's only for entities loaded in current session. This method, **session.update(object)** is meant for attaching object from another tier to current session to track and, possible, update at the end.

In your case it's just an NOOP. It'll sourly throw if:

```
Email email = new Email("andre", "girafa", "hi");

Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

int id = session.save(email);
Email anotherEmail = new Email("", "", "");
anotherEmail.id = id;

session.update(anotherEmail);    // will throw
```

You could read more about update method semantics on [Hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/objectstate-detached.html).

Answer (score 6):

No error because it's the same instance you're updating.

The error is thrown if a DIFFERENT persistent instance is present in the session and you try to update().

Comment: i think it is not `DIFFERENT persistent instance`, it is `DIFFERENT detached instance`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with a session.flush()? To see if that raises the exception (sometimes commit may not flush data depending on flush mode).

Although I would say the exception is only thrown if the object was updated outside the scope of the current session, let's say by a concurrent client.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you always stick to `EntityManager.merge` instead of Hibernate `update` method, `update` is quite confusing.

I found this [article](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate) explain very clear which I always refer to.

> As with persist and save, the update method is an “original” Hibernate
>   method that was present long before the merge method was added. Its
>   semantics differs in several key points:
>
> - it acts upon passed object (its return type is void); the update    method transitions the passed object from detached to persistent
>     state;
> - this method throws an exception if you pass it a transient    entity.
>
> In the following example we save the object, then evict (detach) it
>   from the context, then change its name and call update. Notice that we
>   don’t put the result of the update operation in a separate variable,
>   because the update takes place on the person object itself. Basically
>   we’re reattaching the existing entity instance to the persistence
>   context — something the JPA specification does not allow us to do.

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("John");
session.save(person);
session.evict(person);

person.setName("Mary");
session.update(person);
```

> Trying to call update on a transient instance will result in an
>   exception. The following will not work:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("John");
session.update(person); // PersistenceException!
```

In order to understand the part above, you need to understand the difference between`transient` and `detached` object.